# Getting value VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Apparently, I'm trying to get the values from column b on excel and display each value in separate sheets..starting from sheet5. However, the code below seems to start from index 13 instead of the designated index 10. On my sheet5 it shows value 113, Sheet6 it shows 114...How can I solve this?

```
Sub InvoiceForm()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim buffer As Long
    buffer = ws.Range("B29").Value    'Getting the number of rows exist for column b'
    Dim a As Long
    a = 10
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 5 To (i + buffer - 1)
            If (a <= buffer + a - 1 And wks.CodeName = "Sheet" & i) Then
                With wks
                  .Range("J2") = ws.Range("B" & a).Value
                End With
             a = a + 1
             End If
        Next i
   Next wks
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `For i = 5 To (i + buffer - 1)` evaluates to 5 to 4 and does not execute at all.

Comment: To debug you must understand the value of your values; add this and it will output to the Immediate window: `Debug.Print "i = " & i`

Comment: Debug your condition: `Debug.Print buffer + a - 1`

Comment: Also note that your `a` is incrementing `a = a + 1` so each sheet will get a different cell `ws.Range("C" & a).Value`

Comment: you say _"to get the values from column b"_ but your code (`.Range("J2") = ws.Range("C" & a).Value`) gets them from column C